# Using a Sequence with H2 Causes Unable to locate row for retrieval

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

Our production database is Postgres. For a table, we are using a sequence to generate data for one of the non-id columns. This sequence is defined like so and executes from a Flyway migration:

```
create sequence check_number_seq minvalue 1000 maxvalue 9999 cycle;
alter table guest_check alter column check_number set default nextval('check_number_seq'::regclass);
```

The entity has the column defined as:

```
@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
@Column(nullable = false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Integer checkNumber;
```

When running against Postgres this all works great. Unfortunately, it doesn't work when running against H2 which is what we use for testing. I've added a `@Sql` script to run on the tests with a slightly modified version of the sequence creation to work with H2:

```
create sequence IF NOT EXISTS check_number_seq minvalue 1000 maxvalue 9999 cycle;
alter table guest_check alter column check_number set default nextval('check_number_seq');
```

But when the tests run against the table, they all fail with the same error:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unable to locate row for retrieval of generated properties: [com.foo.entity.thing.GuestCheck#1000];
```

I tried changing the H2 mode and dialect to Postgres but it doesn't resolve the issue. We're using **Spring Boot 1.5.1**.

The work around for now is that we're running our tests against a Postgres DB but I'd really like to get back to H2 for the ease of use.

Comment: What is the H2 connection string? Do you set something like `jdbc:h2:mem:play;MODE=PostgreSQL;LOCK_MODE=0`?

Comment: care to say what is `@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)` because it isn't JPA. Debugging would lead you to look in the JPA providers log at the SQL issued

Comment: @StanislavL yes, that is exactly what I set.

Comment: @NeilStockton It is a Hibernate API annotation

Comment: @Gregg, Struggling with the same issue: H2and value, generated from sequence.  Have you found any solution for it?

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet.

Answer (score 0):

I constructed a minimal test for using sequence for non id column ( http://peter.risko.hu/java_incubator/h2_sequence_for_non_id_jpa.zip ).

However, I can't reproduce the problem with it.

This is my DAO:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "guest_check")
public class GuestCheck {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String id;

    @Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
    @Column(nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false, name = "check_number")
    private Integer checkNumber;

    public Integer getCheckNumber() {
        return checkNumber;
    }

    public void setCheckNumber(Integer checkNumber) {
        this.checkNumber = checkNumber;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "guestCheck, id: " + id + ", checkNo.:" + checkNumber;
    }
}
```

And this is my test:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        GuestCheck guestCheck = new GuestCheck();
        guestCheck.setId("id " + i);
        guestCheckRepository.save(guestCheck);
    }

    List<GuestCheck> guestChecks = guestCheckRepository.findAll();
    for (GuestCheck guestCheck : guestChecks) {
        System.out.println("guestCheck: " + guestCheck);
    }
}
```

And this is the output:

```
guestCheck: guestCheck, id: id 0, checkNo.:1000
guestCheck: guestCheck, id: id 1, checkNo.:1001
guestCheck: guestCheck, id: id 2, checkNo.:1002
guestCheck: guestCheck, id: id 3, checkNo.:1003
guestCheck: guestCheck, id: id 4, checkNo.:1004
guestCheck: guestCheck, id: id 5, checkNo.:1005
guestCheck: guestCheck, id: id 6, checkNo.:1006
guestCheck: guestCheck, id: id 7, checkNo.:1007
guestCheck: guestCheck, id: id 8, checkNo.:1008
guestCheck: guestCheck, id: id 9, checkNo.:1009
```

Maybe I misunderstood something?

Comment: Thanks. The only real difference is your `DAOConfigH2`. I'm wiring all that up in a properties file and I have a main Application class that has `@SpringBootApplication` which does everything your `DAOConfigH2` per each of its annotations. So not sure if that makes a difference or not.